# put character into file at cursor, vim

Tags: unicode, vim

Okay, so here’s the script that I’ve written so far:

```
function MkCheck()  
   put = \"✓\"  
endfunction
```

And it works all right, but it inserts the check mark on a line all by itself. I want to insert it right at where the cursor currently is. Is there any way to get `put` to place the character right before (or right after) the cursor?

Comment: From `:help linewise-register`: “With the `:put` command, Vim always inserts the text in the next line.” As @Birei’s answer suggests, you can use `execute "normal"` to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enter in `insert` mode, append the character and return to `normal` mode:

```
function MkCheck()  
   execute "normal! i✓\<ESC>"
endfunction
```

Comment: consider using `normal!`, since if users map `i` to something else other than insert, `normal i` wouldn't work.  :P

Answer (score 1):

The `:put` command, like most Ex commands, is linewise: it doesn't really care about the position of the cursor in the line.

You can use the `:normal` command to execute a normal mode command like `i✓`:

```
function MkCheck()
    normal i✓
endfunction
```